# How to collapse 2D array by eliminating all empty/null entries

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, functional-programming

I have a 2D container with sample data as below:

```
NULL  1
NULL  2
3     NULL
NULL  4
5     NULL
```

And I wanna **collapse upwards** get rid of all the NULL entries on the way, and result to be like:

```
3     1
5     2
NULL  4
```

Can this be done in a functional way? E.g. I can think of using `foldLeft` to construct a new container and add each row manually, but then when I add the rows, it still needs to use a for loop to find the next empty spot. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: @NicholasK Because it can be implemented by Java (or any other lang)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since an `Int` value can't be `null`, and in this context it would make the inner array type `Array[Any]` (not very useful), I'm going to use `String` instead, which can be `null`.

```
val container :Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, "1")
                                           ,Array(null, "2")
                                           ,Array("3", null)
                                           ,Array(null, "4")
                                           ,Array("5", null))

val as = container.flatMap(s => Option(s(0)))
val bs = container.flatMap(s => Option(s(1)))
val res = as.zipAll(bs, null, null).map(t => Array(t._1, t._2))
//res: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(3, 1), Array(5, 2), Array(null, 4))
```

---

For 2D arrays of various lengths/widths we can take a different approach. Perhaps a bit more complicated but also safer as it makes fewer assumptions about the input. It just has to be transposable (all rows the same length). It even works if the `container` is empty.

```
val container :Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, "1", "6")
                                           ,Array(null, "2", null)
                                           ,Array("3", null, "7")
                                           ,Array(null, "4", "8")
                                           ,Array("5", null, "9"))

val collapsed = container.transpose.map(_.flatMap(Option(_)))
val maxLen = collapsed.foldLeft(0)(_ max _.length)
val res = collapsed.map(_.padTo(maxLen,null)).transpose
//res: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(3, 1, 6)
//                                 ,Array(5, 2, 7)
//                                 ,Array(null, 4, 8)
//                                 ,Array(null, null, 9))
```

Comment: What if there are more columns than 2?

Comment: @texasbruce; see my addition.

Answer (score 1):

> As per `comment` mentioned in `jwvh's` answer, here is the version for
>   more number of columns:

```
val container1 :Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, "1")
                                           ,Array(null, "2")
                                           ,Array("3", null)
                                           ,Array(null, "4")
                                           ,Array("5", null))

val container2 :Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(null, "1","7")
                                              ,Array(null, "2",null)
                                              ,Array("3", null,"8")
                                              ,Array(null, "4",null)
                                              ,Array("5", null,"6"))


 def collapseUpwards(con: Array[Array[String]]) = {
   val noNullArrays = con.map(s =>s.zipWithIndex.
                      map(s1=>Option( s(s1._2)))).transpose.map(_.flatten)
   val maxArraySize = noNullArrays.map(_.size).max
   noNullArrays.map(x=>x++Array.fill(maxArraySize-x.size)(null)).transpose
 }
```

**Test**

```
scala> collapseUpwards(container1)
res12: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(3, 1), Array(5, 2), Array(null, 4))

scala> collapseUpwards(container2)
res13: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(3, 1, 7), Array(5, 2, 8), Array(null, 4, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter for this.
For the sake of the example, I'll use tuples, in order to end with the following:

```
val tuplesList = List( (null, 1), (null, 2), (3, null), (null, 4), (5, null))

tuplesList.filter(_._1 != null) :: tuplesList.reverse.find(_._1 == null).toList
```

The first segment keeps all the elements in which the first element of the tuple is not null, while the second part reverses the list, finds the first element in which the "key" is null, and converts it to a List, empty if no element is found or a one-element list if a match is found.

Comment: The `tuplesList` is type `List[(Any, Any)]` and the result is `List[Product with Serializable]`. Difficult to extract useful data from that.